# C++ preprocessor variable defined in project configuration in eclipse, but invisible to C++ indexer

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

I use preprocessor variables to detect whether code is built for tests or production (I'm aware that you souldn't do this, but that's not the issue).

I have added an `emc_test` preprocessor variable in `Project` -> `C++ General` -> `Paths and Symbols` -> `# Symbols`, but C++ indexed doesn't see it, which results in blocks guarded by `#ifdef emc_test` being grayed out and sybmols inside aren't visible code completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had two build configurations one for tests (with `emc_test` defined) and another for release. I had assumed that C++ index will use whatever configuration is active, and this was not the case.

In `C++ General` -> `Indexer` there is entry that controls which configuration is the source of `C++` preprocessor symbols. And by default eclpise had "Use fixed build configuration" selected.

[image: Screenshot od the setting]